# No consigo enviar un archivo por ftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

```
from ftplib import FTP
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path(f'C:/Users/User/Desktop/whatsapp/output.avi')

with FTP('27.0.172.240', 'ftps', '*******') as ftp, open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        ftp.storbinary(f'STOR /', file) 

¿sabéis que podría ser?
```

el servidor FTP funciona perfectamente , lo monte yo en un servidor y puedo conectame sin problemas desde filezilla

recibo este error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\whatsapp\capture3.py", line 73, in <module>
    ftp.storbinary(f'STOR /', file)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 491, in storbinary
    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 386, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 352, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 279, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 252, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Couldn't open the file
```

Comment: Busca `HTTP error 550`, según [este sitio](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/correo-electronico/cuestiones-tecnicas/error-550-causas-y-soluciones/) es porque el servidor ftp no está dando permiso o te has equivocado con dirección, usuario o clave.

Comment: si ya lo miré, la ruta al archivo locas esta bien seguro, la ruta al FTP no se como ponerla si no es de esta forma.

Comment: El servidor usa el puerto 21? Quizás esta consulta te aporte algo más de luz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658710/12988819